# Create org.json.JSONObject from a class object by using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following Java class

```
public static class LogItem {
    public Long timestamp;
    public Integer level;
    public String topic;
    public String type;
    public String message;
}
```

and I want to convert an `ArrayList<LogItem>` into the following JSON string:

```
{"logitems":[
  {"timestamp":1560924642000, "level":20, "topic":"websocket", "type":"status", "message":"connected (mobile)"},
  ...
]}`
```

I would like to do the following:

```
JSONArray logitems = new JSONArray();
for (DB_LogUtils.LogItem item : items) {
    logitems.put(DB_LogUtils.asJSONObject(item)); // <----
}
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("logitems", logitems);
webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(data.toString(), null);
```

where `DB_LogUtils.asJSONObject` is the following method

```
public static JSONObject asJSONObject(LogItem item) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject logitem = new JSONObject();
    logitem.put("timestamp", item.timestamp);
    logitem.put("level",     item.level);
    logitem.put("topic",     item.topic);
    logitem.put("type",      item.type);
    logitem.put("message",   item.message);
    return logitem;
}
```

but instead of doing this manually (like `logitem.put("timestamp", item.timestamp);`) I want to do this with `Gson`, so that I would end up with something like this

```
JSONArray logitems = new JSONArray();
for (DB_LogUtils.LogItem item : items) {
    logitems.put(new Gson().toJSONObject(item)); // <----
}
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("logitems", logitems);
webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(data.toString(), null);
```

in order to not have to edit the code at multiple points when the LogItem class changes.

But `Gson().toJSONObject(...)` does not exist, only `Gson().toJson(...)`, which returns a `String`. I don't want to transition into a `String` only to then parse it with `org.json.JSONObject`.

I ended up using a second class

```
public static class LogItems {
    public List<LogItem> logitems = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

which then let me change the whole code to

```
webViewFragment.onInjectMessage(new Gson().toJson(items), null);
```

where `items` would be of type `LogItems`.

In this case, creating the extra wrapper class was an overall benefit, but I'd still want to know how I can create such a JSONObject from a class by using Gson.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it could be not possible without using for loop to iterate json string into array and store into map with same key.

But you can achieve your solution instead of passing dto pass the list of items into gson object as follow.

```
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add("1560924642000");
    list.add(20);
    list.add("websocket");
    list.add("status");
    list.add("connected (mobile)");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map mp = new HashMap();
    mp.put("ietams", list);
    String json = gson.toJson(mp);
    System.out.println(json);
```

output will be

```
   {"logitems":["1560924642000",20,"websocket","status","connected (mobile)"]}
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: Oh, sorry, I realized I made a bad typo in the question, will fix the expected JSON string now